# How to optimize the for loops in R

Tags: r, loops

I'm trying to loop over a column of a big table with more than 1 million records. The following for loop is taking around 12 hours to get execute currently, which is too much. I've heard of the apply statements that are more efficient, however I haven't tried it yet. Basically the dataset looks like the following:

```
patient_id  date       enrolled_date
101        2018-03-02  2016-02-09
101        2018-06-23  2016-09-14
101        2018-01-19  NA
102        2017-04-20  2017-09-11
102        2017-06-15  NA
```

The output should look like the following:

```
patient_id   date        enrolled_date
101        2018-03-02  2016-02-09
101        2018-06-23  2016-09-14
101        2018-01-19  2018-01-19
102        2017-04-20  2017-09-11
102        2017-09-05  NA
```

Logic: For patient 101, the third entry has date: 2018-01-19, and it's obviously 30 days more than the max(previous entries of enrolled_date)=2016-09-14 for the same patient, thus the NA has been replaced with the corresponding date value. However for patient 102, for the second entry, the value in the date column is < 30 days from the previous entry of the enrolled date for the same patient, thus it'll remain NA only.

```
for(i in 2:nrow(df)){

  x <- df$patient_id[i]
  df_1 <- df[df$patient_id==x,]
  for( j in 1:nrow(df_1)){

       df_1$enrolled_dt[j] <- as.Date(ifelse(df_1$date[j]- max(df_2$enrolled_dt[1:j-1],na.rm = TRUE)>30,df_2$date[j],NA),origin="1970-01-01") 


   }


  df[which(df$patient_id==x),"enrolled_dt"]<- df_1[,"enrolled_dt"]
}
```

It would be great if someone can help me out here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? R's data objects are not exactly designed to be used with loops.

Comment: Basically, it's a huge dataset at patient level and I'm trying to populate this column "col_3" using the subset of the same table(which is created for every id). The loop is trying to compare it's date(col_4) with the max entry of date appearing in col_3 and in case the difference is >30. t's populating the value appearing in col_4, else keeping as is.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: This loop is working, however it's taking an entire day to run. Please suggest possible ways of execution time reduction

Comment: Please give enough information to allow us to understand your data and question. At the very least you need to give examples of what your data frames look like – at the moment all we have is one of them (and not in a format that I can copy and paste into R). Also, a good explanation of your goal would be helpful – i.e what your rational or requirement is.